# New to coding, can't get my trigger code to work

Tags: apex, trigger, approval-process

I am new to coding and am looking for a little help to make my code approve a custom object (`Site_Call_Performance`) if it is stuck in an approval process for more then 24 hours.  I have a workflow that will check a checkbox after that time and am looking to write some trigger code that will pick up that checkbox and approve the record.  Currently, my code raises the below error:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature for line 3 and 4

```
trigger approve on Site_Call_Performance__c (after update) {
for (Site_Call_Performance__c a : Trigger.new) if (a.Approval_Checkbox__c = TRUE)  {
a.setComments('Auto Approving the record after 1 day');
a.setAction('Approve');}
}
```

Comment: you should probably start out with [Trailheads: apex triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_triggers/units/apex_triggers_intro) for a better understanding

Comment: that's exactly what i used to get this far haha, i will review again but it doesn't tell me anything about method errors.

Comment: So I think you may need to rethink this design, You need to know how long it has been in the approval status, do you know that?  So when it gets triggered for approval do you have a field being updated to say it's in progress?  Are you tracking when it was submitted for approval? And shouldn't this be a batch job?  You should do more research into what you need to do, this trigger won't do it..

Comment: yes, once it is sent into the approval process the status changes to "Submitted".  Once that status changes I have a time dependent workflow to check a checkbox.  So to simplify I need to approve this record if a checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it, I eyeballed it but any mistakes should be minimal.  Check out  this to [learn more](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_approval.htm) about Approvals.  I wrote this assuming that your approvals checkbox is being update correctly.

Your code wasn't working because you cannot do this on the object.  You were also trying to assign `Approval_Checkbox__c` to true in an If statement

```
a.setComments('Auto Approving the record after 1 day');
a.setAction('Approve');}
```

So you need to properly build out the `Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest`

```
trigger approve on Site_Call_Performance__c (after update) 
{
    List<Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest> reqList = new List<Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest>();
    Set<ID> scpIDs = new Set<ID>();
    for (Site_Call_Performance__c a : Trigger.new)
    {
        if (a.Approval_Checkbox__c)
        {
            scpIDs.add(a.Id);
        }
    }

    Set<Id> pIds = (new Map<Id, ProcessInstance>([SELECT Id,Status,TargetObjectId FROM ProcessInstance where Status='Pending' and TargetObjectId in :scpIds ])).keySet();
    Set<Id> pInstanceWorkitems = (new Map<Id, ProcessInstanceWorkitem>([SELECT Id,ProcessInstanceId FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem WHERE ProcessInstanceId in :pIds])).keySet();

    List<Approval.ProcessWorkItemRequest> approve = New List<Approval.ProcessWorkItemRequest>(); 

    for (Id pInstanceWorkitemsId : pInstanceWorkitems)
    {
        Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest req = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest();
        req.setComments('Auto Approving the record after 1 day');
        req.setAction('Approve'); 
        req.setWorkitemId(pInstanceWorkitemsId);

        approve.add(req);
    }

List<Approval.ProcessResult> result = Approval.process(approve);

}
```

Comment: appreciate your help but I am getting a method error on req.setAction('Approve');

Comment: ok awesome.  This code saved, but is running into the problem that it can't be in more then one approval process at a time, so do i need to recall or reject this and then submit and approve this all in the trigger?

Comment: I only have one approval process set up for this object.  Do i need to add entry criteria based on the approval status to weed this out?

Comment: right now because there is only one process i have entry based on record type, and there is only one record type.  Everything goes through the same approval process right now

Comment: does it affect things if it is already in an approval process before this is triggered?

Comment: ah ok, well the record will already be in an approval process when that box gets checked.  Do i need to code it to recall, change the status to something different and then resubmit to a different approval process that approves it?

Comment: do i need to declare Site Call a?  it doesn't recognize that variable anymore

Comment: im so happy you are helping this was way over my head!   It is not recognizing the scp variable

Comment: I liked Tushars but i am getting a method error at allReq.add(req2); and List<Approval.ProcessResult> result2 = Approval.process(allReq).   Rewrote because spelling!

Comment: you are the freaking man!    thank you so much.   Tushar i appreciate your help too!   This fired perfect.

Answer (score 3):

This is not exactly an answer, but since you specified you're new to coding I wanted to drop some tips to improve your code:

1. Always indent after opening a new construct (for, if, etc)
2. Use `{` and `}` for those code blocks (even one-line ones), to make your code more readable
3. `=` is for assignemnt, `==` for equality.
4. there is no need to do `== true`. Just assume the variable has the value true/false

This is how it would look

```
trigger approve on Site_Call_Performance__c (after update) {
  for (Site_Call_Performance__c a : Trigger.new) {
     if (a.Approval_Checkbox__c)  { //would be  == TRUE if you choose to leave that in
       a.setComments('Auto Approving the record after 1 day');
       a.setAction('Approve');
     }  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You first need to query the `ProcessInstanceWorkitem` to get the approval process Id and then need to Approved or Reject it.

```
trigger approve on Site_Call_Performance__c (after update) {
  Set<Id> scpIds = new Set<Id>;
  for (Site_Call_Performance__c a : Trigger.new) 
     if (a.Approval_Checkbox__c)
         scpIds .add(a.Id);


    Set<Id> pIds = (new Map<Id, ProcessInstance>([SELECT Id,Status,TargetObjectId FROM ProcessInstance where Status='Pending' and TargetObjectId in :scpIds ])).keySet();
    Set<Id> pInstanceWorkitems = (new Map<Id, ProcessInstanceWorkitem>([SELECT Id,ProcessInstanceId FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem WHERE ProcessInstanceId in :pIds])).keySet();

    List<Approval.ProcessResult> allReq = New List<Approval.ProcessResult>(); 
    for (Id pInstanceWorkitemsId:pInstanceWorkitems){
        system.debug(pInstanceWorkitemsId);
            Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest req2 = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest();
            req2.setComments('Autro Approve.');
            req2.setAction('Approve'); //to Reject use 'Reject'
            req2.setNextApproverIds(new Id[] {UserInfo.getUserId()});

            // Use the ID from the newly created item to specify the item to be worked
            req2.setWorkitemId(pInstanceWorkitemsId);

            // Add the request for approval
            allReq.add(req2);
    }
    List<Approval.ProcessResult> result2 =  Approval.process(allReq);
}
```

Note: I write this code directly here so maybe I missed some bracket.You can check them.

Comment: Thanks Tushar,  still getting Method errors around "allReq.add(req2);  and "List<Approval.ProcessingResult> result2 = Approval.process(allReq); along with unexpected tokens (<,>,=,new) on line  2